# RF Communication Simulation Software

Tags: software, modeling, sdr

I was wondering about free software for modelling RF communications, such as creating a transponder equipment line up, changing equipment parameters etc and modelling performances like BER, S/N, Phase Noise, IQ Imbalances etc...

I know of SystemVue and ADS by Keysight... Are there free alternatives out there? Maybe python libraries? Is GNURadio any good?

I did a search but there was recommendations for RF circuits only.

Comment: GNU Radio is awesome! (PS: I'm the maintainer of GNU Radio, and whether it's what you want is hard to tell from what you say – there's a lot of impairment models in GNU Radio and for GNU Radio, but you don't seem to be overly clear on what level of things you want to work. see [the guided tutorials' intro chapter](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org))

Comment: Impressive Mr. M.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, but only a very tiny fraction of GNU Radio's code is written by me :)